# Firebase CrashReporting + Fabric

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-crash-reporting, google-fabric

As announced by Google, the Firebase Crash Reporting is joining forces with Fabric. [Here's a link](https://techcrunch.com/2017/05/17/google-firebase-gets-fabric-integration-better-analytics-and-an-alpha-program/)

The exact details of how is this going to happen are abstract. But for developers who were using Firebase Crash Reporting, does this mean that they have to create a new account on Fabric and integrate its SDK and remove the one from Firebase?

I know I could wait until Google does the actual implementation, but switching from one SDK to another is not the best approach, if anyone has any insight on this...

Answer (score 3):

The following is the text from the Firebase console when looking at Crash Reporting for the first time without any existing data.  There's no additional information available about how exactly it's going to work.

> Fabric’s Crashlytics
>
> In the future, Fabric’s Crashlytics will become our primary crash
> reporter because it provides advanced tools for solving stability
> issues. If you’d like to be an early adopter, you can get a head start
> by using Crashlytics on Fabric’s platform.
>
> Crash Reporting
>
> If you prefer to monitor stability in Firebase, you still have access
> to Firebase Crash Reporting, which equips you with the essential tools
> you need to track and resolve crashes. Eventually, Firebase Crash
> Reporting will be seamlessly upgraded to Crashlytics.

Comment: I guess there really is not much info for now, so I'll just implement both

Comment: Yes, that's certainly an option on Android (but not on iOS).

Answer (score 1):

according to the Google groups discussion, they recommend ppl to use crashytics for now if they don't have any strong preferences.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/firebase-talk/_uUuJm0wui8/rHuWYKbABwAJ

> Ian Barber
>
> We're mainly trying to signal forward intent - the feature sets are slightly different so I appreciate you may prefer to use Firebase Crash on a new app, but for those with no standing inclination we're recommending they go with crashlytics.